# Expand a div with description under 4 images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I cant figure out hot to make a code that works, i have 4 images side by side and i need a description section under the images, this section should be hidden and when i click over an image the correct information should be displayed

```
<section class="img" style="text-align:center;">            
    <div class="container" onclick="select(1)" onclick="hideunhide()"">
        <img src="img/1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="container" onclick="select(2)">
        <img src="img/2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="container" onclick="select(3)">
        <img src="img/3.jpg">
    </div>    
    <div class="container" onclick="select(4)">
        <img src="img/4.jpg">
    </div>   

</div>
</section>
<section id="description">
    <div class="info" id="desc1">
        <h1>people</h1>
        <p>time</p>
        <p>country</p>
    </div>
    <div class="info" id="desc2">
        <h1>people</h1>
        <p>time</p>
        <p>country</p>
    </div>
    <div class="info" id="desc3">
        <h1>people</h1>
        <p>time</p>
        <p>country</p>
    </div>
    <div class="info" id="desc4">
        <h1>people</h1>
        <p>time</p>
        <p>country</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

The javascript im using:

```
<script>
    function hideunhide() {
        var obj = document.getElementById("description");
        if(obj.style.display == "block")
            obj.style.display = "none";
        else
            obj.style.display = "block";
    };
    function select()
        var obj = document.getElementByID(select())
</script>
```

I know that im messed up over the select(), but cant figure it out. Any help please? I can use html, css and javascript. Thanks

Edit: Added CSS

```
div.container {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 25px;
    border: solid 5px #333333;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
div.container:hover {
    border: solid 5px #fff;
}
.info {
    border: solid 5px #333333;
    text-align: center
}
```

Comment: You will need to provide your styling.

Comment: i have added the style

Comment: how is it like? you want to hide info already displayed when i click image or  as i keep clicking the info should display?

Comment: something like this?? https://jsbin.com/fujigedewi/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: info by default should be hidden. if img1 is clicked, it should unhide the img1 information. if img1 is clicked again should hide the information. If img2 is clicked while img1 information is shown it should switch information

Comment: RRR something like that! with the hide option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second version, based on comments, the text flows across the page width, responsive, meaning a text is always direct under its image even when image break line (using media query and a minimal script)

*Note: working on a CSS only version, though not quite satisfied yet ([fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/4qumxfLz/4/))*

```js
(function(lastimg) {
  document.querySelector("#img-select").addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input') {
      if (lastimg == e.target) {
        e.target.checked = false;
        lastimg = null;
      } else {
        lastimg = e.target;
      }      
    }
  });
}());
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container > label {
  flex: 1;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  order: 1;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.container > div {
  flex: 1;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  order: 5;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.container label img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container input, .container input ~ div {
  display: none;
}

.container input:checked ~ div {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}
.container div div {
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  
  .container > label {
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }
  .container > label:nth-of-type(3),
  .container > label:nth-of-type(4) {
    order: 3;
  }
  .container > div:nth-of-type(1),
  .container > div:nth-of-type(2) {
    order: 2;
  }
  
}
@media screen and (max-width: 325px) {

  .container > label {
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }

  .container > label:nth-of-type(1),
  .container > div:nth-of-type(1) {
    order: 1;
  }
  .container > label:nth-of-type(2),
  .container > div:nth-of-type(2) {
    order: 2;
  }
  .container > label:nth-of-type(3),
  .container > div:nth-of-type(3) {
    order: 3;
  }
  .container > label:nth-of-type(4),
  .container > div:nth-of-type(4) {
    order: 4;
  }

}
```

```html
<div id="img-select" class="container">
  <label for="img1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x200" alt="">
  </label>
  <label for="img2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x200" alt="">
  </label>
  <label for="img3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x200" alt="">
  </label>
  <label for="img4">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x200" alt="">
  </label>

  <div>
    <input id="img1" type="radio" name="img-descr">
    <div>Some text for img 1 that flow across full page width</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="img2" type="radio" name="img-descr">
    <div>Some text for img 2</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="img3" type="radio" name="img-descr">
    <div>Some text for img 3</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="img4" type="radio" name="img-descr">
    <div>Some text for img 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

In this, the first version, the text is positioned under its image all the time, and will be responsive as well on smaller screens. (this version is still use a minimal script)

```js
(function(lastimg) {
  document.querySelector("#img-select").addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input') {
      if (lastimg == e.target) {
        e.target.checked = false;
        lastimg = null;
      } else {
        lastimg = e.target;
      }      
    }
  });
}());
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
label img {
  display: block;
}
label input, label span {
  display: none;
}

label input:checked ~ span {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="img-select">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="img-descr">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x200" alt="">
    <span>Some text for img 1</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="img-descr">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x200" alt="">
    <span>Some text for img 2</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="img-descr">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x200" alt="">
    <span>Some text for img 3</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="img-descr">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x200" alt="">
    <span>Some text for img 4</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: something like this, "but text for img" should take all the page width, and when second click on img should hide text.

Comment: @TomasBond Text gets hidden now on a 2:nd click, but I will fix text take all width

Comment: @TomasBond Updated my answer. What browser do you use?

Comment: i use Firefox, but should be compatible with most browsers. I see all text on same position ( i think this is just because they arent centered on the page as i inted on my page) 2 nd click hide isnt working for me, text just stays there

Comment: you seem to know soo much about this, when seen in small screen like phones, it should pop up under the image that are displayed under the current line, if images are splited in 2x2 structure, the information from img 1 and 2 should pop up under those images, and info from img3 and 4 should pop up at the bottom of the page. hard to understand, hope it isnt hard for you to understand

Comment: @TomasBond: I understand what you mean, though first, I just tested this on Firefox, Chrome, Edge, IE11 and it works on all of them. Which version of Firefox do you have and are you testing my sample alone or did you embed it into your own code?

Comment: i click the run code snippet to test the code, im using firefox 45.0.1

Comment: @TomasBond: I use 44.0.2 which works .. will update now and test the latest

Comment: @TomasBond: I updated to FF 45.0.1 and the snippets works as they should ... if you refresh and try again, still not working? ... Do you use Windows or Linux?

Comment: @TomasBond I also updated my answer to work in a 1-by-1 and 2-by-2 structure.

Comment: not working in firefor neither in chrome, im using windows10

Comment: @TomasBond So am I .. working in both for me, so the question is, what is it that doesn't work? ... Could you show me a screen dump?

Comment: oh i think i didnt explain myself. when description from image 2 is being show (you recently click to see that description. when you press again on that image the description should hide, like hide/unhide button

Comment: @TomasBond Now I think I got it :) ... updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

PLease try this, hope it might help buddy! its working basic on my console, you can enhance it more:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <section class="img" style="text-align:center;">            
            <div class="container" onclick="hideunhide(1)">
                <img src="img/1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="container" onclick="hideunhide(2)">
                <img src="img/2.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="container" onclick="hideunhide(3)">
                <img src="img/3.jpg">
            </div>    
            <div class="container" onclick="hideunhide(4)">
                <img src="img/4.jpg">
            </div>   
        </section>

        <section id="description">
            <div id="1" style="display:none;">
                <h1>people</h1>
                <p>time</p>
                <p>country</p>
            </div>
            <div id="2" style="display:none;">
                <h1>people</h1>
                <p>time</p>
                <p>country</p>
            </div>
            <div id="3" style="display:none;">
                <h1>people</h1>
                <p>time</p>
                <p>country</p>
            </div>
            <div id="4" style="display:none;">
                <h1>people</h1>
                <p>time</p>
                <p>country</p>
            </div>
        </section>
 <script>

              function hideunhide(id) {
                  var obj = document.getElementById(id);
                  if(obj.style.display == "block")
                      obj.style.display = "none";
                  else
                    obj.style.display = "block";
                };

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its closer, when i hit img1 should appear the description, if i hit img2 while img1 description is being shown it should switch descriptions.